# How do I vectorize this for-loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I need to vectorize this for loop to speed it up and I'm not sure how to do it.

```
for k=1:n
  x2=x(k)*x(k);
  y(k) = (1-c1*x(k)+c2*x2-(x(k)/60)*x2)/...
         (1+c3*x(k)+c4*x2);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Element-wise [power](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html) (or [multiplication](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html)) and [division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html) is all what you need. I replaced your multiplications of `x(k)` with itself with exponentials.

```
y = (1 - c1*x + c2*x.^2 - x.^3/60) ./ (1 + c3*x + c4*x.^2); % assuming n = numel(x)
% if n ≠ numel(x) then replace all 'x's in above line with x(1:n)
```